# VBA inter-workbook actions- Errors everytime I fix something

Tags: vba, excel

I have some pretty simple code but I keep running into errors every time I fix something. Not sure if I'm just doing something completely wrong. All I'm trying to do is copy a range of cells from a workbook on another drive into `ThisWorkbook` as a picture.

First plan of attack:

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook

BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").Copy
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").Pictures.Paste
```

Error that results: `Object doesn't support this property or method` on `test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").Pictures.Paste`

So I broke it down more based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288588/excel-vba-error-438-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method) but I didn't quite understand what they were accomplishing.

Second attempt:

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook


BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").Copy
test.Sheets("Summary").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("B64").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
```

Error that results: `Select Method of Worksheet class failed` on `test.Sheets("Summary").Select`

Then I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949893/vba-error-1004-select-method-of-range-class-failed) but it seemed like I was doing the same thing but just a different way. Now I don't know what to do. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook

BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").CopyPicture
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: I got the `Object doesn't support this property or method` error on `test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").Paste`

Comment: The workbook I'm trying to copy from has Bloomberg formulas in it, if that makes a difference. I have Bloomberg so I don't think there would be an issue.

Comment: Bloomberg formulas won't make any difference for this. I changed it to `.PasteSpecial`. That will correct it.